# Total scale is a significant mediator, but not subscales?

Tags: mediation

I am running mediation analysis where there is a significant mediating effect through the total scale for the construct I'm looking at. However, when I run a parallel mediation using the subscales in the same measure, non of the indirect paths are significant. How can I best interpret this?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a variety of different reasons for this finding. The composite (overall scale) score is likely more reliable (contains less measurement error variance) than the individual subscale scores, potentially giving you greater statistical power to detect an effect with the overall score. The composite score likely also contains less specific variance and more "shared" (common) variance than each individual subscale thus reflecting an at least partially different construct than each subscale. In addition, with multiple parallel mediators, you have more (correlated) predictors and more free parameters in your model, potentially increasing your standard errors and possibly lowering your power.